# Galaxy S5 screen won't turn on, how to factory reset with Odin?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, att

So, my mom has had a Galaxy S5 phone for awhile, but I went into her room today and found her old Galaxy S5. She claims it's not working properly, so I offered to try and fix it. I spent a few minutes messing with the phone and I noticed that I could not get the screen to turn on, but the phone vibrates when I plug it in, and my PC makes the device connected sound. I'd like to know how to reset the phone to factory settings, but also flash a custom ROM onto it. (In this case, I want to flash Resurrection Remix) My mom will be okay with this since she doesn't use the phone I'm trying to work with anymore. The phone is of the AT&T variant.

Edit: I asked my mom about the screen problem. She stated that the top of the screen started to dim and within 48 hours the screen wouldn't turn on at all.

Comment: You're gonna need quite some blind operations to get that done... esp. if you want custom ROMs, since the *de facto* go-to recovery (TWRP) is fully touch-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this guide for restoring stock rom**

https://www.idroidspace.com/official-stock-rom-for-samsung-galaxy-s5/

**Follow this guide to install TWRP which is a custom recovery which is needed to install any custom rom.**

http://www.droidviews.com/install-twrp-recovery-samsung-galaxy-s5/